# "Pyinstaller error" raise ImportError("No module named " + target_package_name) ImportError: No module named _bootlocale

Tags: python, import, module, pyinstaller, exe

Every time I use pyinstaller to convert my .py into .exe the error:

```
raise ImportError("No module named " + target_package_name)
ImportError: No module named _bootlocale"
```

shows up and just gives me `emptyBuild` and `Dist` folders. I've updated my python and tried youtube tutorials but none of them work for me.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.10? PyInstaller doesn't support it yet. Switch back to 3.9 would be fine.

Comment: I fixed the issue. all I had to do was download "pip3 install https://github.com/rokm/pyinstaller/archive/refs/heads/python-3.10.zip" and it fixed the installer. And I am using python 10

Comment: Consider posting it as an answer? Since python 3.10 already released and pyinstaller didn't support it. Some people using python3.10 and pyinstaller might be confused.

Answer (score 0):

just add
--exclude-module _bootlocale

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).